# Wrapping method name in definition

Tags: python, function, methods, word-wrap

Is it possible to wrap the method name in the definition of a function? I have an exceptionally long method name and I'm wondering if it's possible to wrap it like so:

```
# method name is my_really_long_method_name_wow_this_is_really_long
def my_really_long_method_name_
        wow_this_is_really_long():
    pass
```

I have tried doing this, but I get a syntax error:

```py
def my_really_long_method_name_\
        wow_this_is_really_long():
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, wrapping your function name is not possible, even if Python supports unlimited length of function names. Longer function names are not unusual, but making them so long they need two rows of a screen actually shows something is really wrong with your naming convention.

Btw, Python recommends a line length (in total) of 79 characters. We are not in the 80's anymore with old screens so you can ignore that limit, but it gives you a good indication.

Reference: [PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I am following Roy Osherove's guide for naming unit test methods, but I'd also like my tests to be PEP0008 compliant (wrap to 79 characters). I guess I'll have to work out a way of renaming my tests so that they are less than 80 characters.

Comment: One possible way to solve this is to create classes to structure your code and to split it into pieces. `Abstraction` is the keyword here. `test1.ExecuteMain()` is easier to read than `ThisIsTest1AndThisExecutesMainTest`